# что это за интерфейс?

Tags: cisco-packet-tracer

до этого мы работали только с FastEthernet поэтому что то незнакомое, да и в инете сложно найти. и как их подключать.[image: Eth и Etc]

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какой именно интерфейс вы имеете в виду

Comment: @r3pl1c4nt Eth0/0/0 и Etc0/1/0